# Why is it not possible to transfer the user token to the API django rest framework?

Tags: kotlin, django-rest-framework, retrofit

There is an API based on the django rest framework, which outputs an order model in which there is a user token, order date, products, and price.

```
    {
        "userToken": "7e0e72e274bbda5e6f3cc9e3563f8c41384a37af",
        "date": "2023-05-14T08:11:05.689723Z",
        "product": [
        ...
        ],
        "price": 170
    },
```

And I am now trying to get data on the token, if you enter this url in the browser bar, you can get a list of orders made by a certain user.

```
base_url/Order/Order/?search=7e0e72e274bbda5e6f3cc9e3563f8c41384a37af
```

I am trying to get all the orders made by the user using this function

```
@GET("Order/Order/")
suspend fun getOrder(@Query("userToken") userToken:String):Response<List<OrderResult>>
```

But in order to receive orders made by a certain user, I receive absolutely all orders.
After that, I tried to change the url, but it didn't work, I still received absolutely all orders.

```
@GET("Order/Order/?search=")
suspend fun getOrder(@Query("userToken") userToken:String):Response<List<OrderResult>>
```

After the Query request failed, I tried using Path, but nothing came from Path at all.

```
@GET("Order/Order/?search={userToken}")
suspend fun getOrder(@Path("userToken") userToken:String):Response<List<OrderResult>>
```

Based on the above, how to make sure that orders related only to a certain user come?

I tried to write a Path and Query in anticipation of the appearance of orders associated with a specific user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to add a query param to the `request`, you need to use the query value to match the parameter name, in your case it would be  `search` not `userToken` in `@Query`

```
//replace "userToken" with "search" inside Query
@GET("Order/Order/")
suspend fun getOrder(@Query("search") userToken: String):Response<List<OrderResult>>
```